# How can I change multiple elements by each array value?

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, foreach

When I check my checkbox and then click the "mark as done" button then the status_result is changing to `done`. It works when I do it for each single. But not if I check all. Then only one status_result is changing:

```js
$('.productdetails-table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var unchecked = [];
        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function () {
            unchecked.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(".selected-products").val(unchecked.join(", "));
    });

  
$(document).on('click', '.edit-done', function () {
    var array = $('.selected-products').val().split(",");
        $.each(array,function(i){
            $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + array[i] + "']").find(".status_result").html('<span style="background-color: #00c0ef" class="label label-primary">done</span>');    
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="pull-right" style="padding:6px 8px; margin-right:-5px;">
      <button style="display: block;" type="button" class="edit-checked edit-done btn btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mark as "done"</button>
 </li>
                            
 <input name="selected-products" class="selected-products" type="text">
<table class="productdetails-table table table-bordered table-hover " style="cursor:pointer">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th>Check</th>
   <th>Status</th>
</tr>

<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="93"><td><input class="check-parent" value="93" type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result detail"  ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="92" data-table="productdetails"><td class="check close_sidebar"><input value="92"  type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result" ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is being caused by an additional space being added after the comma. If you change `$(".selected-products").val(unchecked.join(", "));` to `$(".selected-products").val(unchecked.join(","));` then it'll work.

```js
$('.productdetails-table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var unchecked = [];
        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked:not(#checkAll)"), function () {
            unchecked.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(".selected-products").val(unchecked.join(","));
    });

  
$(document).on('click', '.edit-done', function () {
    var array = $('.selected-products').val().split(",");
        console.log(array)
        $.each(array,function(i){
            $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + array[i] + "']").find(".status_result").html('<span style="background-color: #00c0ef" class="label label-primary">done</span>');    
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="pull-right" style="padding:6px 8px; margin-right:-5px;">
      <button style="display: block;" type="button" class="edit-checked edit-done btn btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mark as "done"</button>
 </li>
                            
 <input name="selected-products" class="selected-products" type="text">
<table class="productdetails-table table table-bordered table-hover " style="cursor:pointer">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th>Check</th>
   <th>Status</th>
</tr>

<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="93"><td><input class="check-parent" value="93" type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result detail"  ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="92" data-table="productdetails"><td class="check close_sidebar"><input value="92"  type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result" ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you may not be familiar with the JavaScript debugger built into your browser. If you learn how to use the debugger, you can track down problems like this in seconds, instead of being stumped and having to ask on Stack Overflow.

You can start right now. Below is a copy of your snippet with a `debugger;` statement added at a strategic location.

Open the developer tools in your browser and then run the snippet. Select both your checkboxes and click the button. It will stop on the `debugger;` statement. In Chrome, you should see a panel like this:

[image: Chrome debugger]

Now take a close look under `Local` and you will see the values in your `array`. It will probably jump right out at you that `"93"` looks correct but `" 92"` has a space in front of it.

Here's the updated snippet; try it out and see what you can discover, and then use the debugger the next time you run into a mystery like this.

```js
$('.productdetails-table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var unchecked = [];
        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function () {
            unchecked.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(".selected-products").val(unchecked.join(", "));
    });

  
$(document).on('click', '.edit-done', function () {
    var array = $('.selected-products').val().split(",");
    debugger;  // This will stop in the JavaScript debugger
        $.each(array,function(i){
            $(".productdetails[data-product_id='" + array[i] + "']").find(".status_result").html('<span style="background-color: #00c0ef" class="label label-primary">done</span>');    
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="pull-right" style="padding:6px 8px; margin-right:-5px;">
      <button style="display: block;" type="button" class="edit-checked edit-done btn btn-block btn-info"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mark as "done"</button>
 </li>
                            
 <input name="selected-products" class="selected-products" type="text">
<table class="productdetails-table table table-bordered table-hover " style="cursor:pointer">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th>Check</th>
   <th>Status</th>
</tr>

<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="93"><td><input class="check-parent" value="93" type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result detail"  ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
<tr class="productdetails" data-product_id="92" data-table="productdetails"><td class="check close_sidebar"><input value="92"  type="checkbox"></td><td class="status_result" ><span style="background-color: #368cbe" class="label label-primary">pending</span></td></tr>
```